# How do I pluck this specific node out of from this JSON array?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an array being returned in `Xcode` which outputs the following:

```
   ["userDetails": {
     id = 31;
     "user_email" = "steve@gmail.com";
     "user_name" = "Steve Downs";
     }, "communities": <__NSArrayI 0x600000245f40>(
     {
     id = 5;
     name = South;
     },
     {
     id = 13;
     name = HurraHarry;
     },
     {
     id = 15;
     name = EnclliffeT;
     }
     )
     ]
```

The code below correctly assigns the values contained within "communities" to their respective variables.

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                  print (json!)

if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!}
                        self.communityIdsArray = arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!}
                        }

                    if let arr = json?["userDetails"] as? [AnyObject] {

                        self.playerId = (arr.flatMap { $0["id"]!} as (AnyObject)) as! [String]
                        print (self.playerId);
                    }
```

However I'm having trouble assigning `id` from `"userDetails"`. How do I take `id` from `"userDetails"` and assign it to self.playerId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
if let dict = json?["userDetails"] as? [String:String] {
    self.playerId = dict["id"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get:   Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[String]'

Comment: I got it working with: self.playerId = [dict["id"]!]

Answer (score -1):

Well the correct would be I believe:

```
guard let item = json?["userDetails"] as? [String: AnyObject],
  self.playerId = item["id"] as? Int else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: The idea could be correct *but* Lefteris is using the property `self.playerId` directly instead of a new variable in the `guard`, this doesn't work like that.